# PDF to CAMT (XML/MT940) conversion

Tags: pdf, xml, conversion

Is there someone who can provide any information about converting PDF documents to the CAMT, appropriate XML or MT940 format?
Target OS is a windows 10 machine.
I appreciate any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the target format here is a very structured report format from the banking industry; MT490 specifically seems to refer to end-of-day reports.

No, PDF is not a structured format. Unless the specific structured file has been explicitly embedded/attached in the PDF, the original structure got lost.

OCR / text extraction methods might work somewhat, but seeing the field you seem to be working in, that's not an option.

Comment: Well, the content of the pdf documents is(are) actually a table(s) with account movements for the bank interface.
A plain xml conversion is not accepted by the interface. This suggests that it must be a special xml variant.

Comment: yes, it definitely is. As said, just exporting the text won't do. I honestly don't see how a banking workflow could involve getting the movements out of a print version back into SWIFT / SEPA.

Comment: There is this [site](http://www.whiterocksoftware.com/2020/07/transfer-excel-to-mt940-swift-file.html) claiming a conversion from xls to mt940. This is perhaps worth a deeper insight...

Comment: again, an excel spreadsheet is very structured data (though it's really a testament on the state of banking that we even need to discuss that the data someone entered manually into an excel spread sheet ends up in SEPA); your PDF *is not*. And frankly, that website screams "malware"; please do not deploy this in a banking environment without isolating the machine you plan to install this on **very** intensely from all the other machines.